# python - Obtaining data from http search

Tags: python, http, url, urllib2, urllib

I'm using python to obtain some data from a catalog in internet, I'm using  urllib2 and urllib. At this point I'm able to generate the url to begin the search, for instance to look for info for a thing called "202061048" the resulting url is:

```
https://archive.stsci.edu/k2/epic/search.php?id=202061048&action=Search
```

At this point I'm interested in the two variables RA and DEC (as described in the resulting page from the url above, RA=06 01 11.779 and DEC=+23 23 43.69).

My question is: How to do that? At this point I have used:

```
handler = urllib2.urlopen(get_url)
raw = handler.read()
print(raw[0:250000])
```

But I'm seeing only a bunch of code, and I'm not sure If under urllib2 is there something to obtain the info I'm looking (RA=06 01 11.779 and DEC=+23 23 43.69 values), and assign those values to a variable in python. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into Beautiful Soup, an HTML/XML parsing library. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: `urllib2` is used only for transfering data between two computer, not to search information in this data. You have to use other modules or functions, at least standard string functions like `find()` or module `re` for regex. But the most useful are modules which parse HTML data like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`